# How to make dice image to Int value? in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I'm making a simple Dice game and a newbie in programing.
I have dice images 1 to 6. I know how to roll it and apply random.

```
@IBAction func rollPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let diceArray=[#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")]
    diceFour.image=diceArray.randomElement()
 }
```

like this.
But I want to match does image with Int data type and do random.
And finaly that I can print the resualt in Int data type value.

I'm trying the dictionary like

```
let diceDictionary = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"):1,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"):2,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"):3,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"):4,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"):5,#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix"):6]
```

but I'm stuck on how can I get the value.
Please anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the dictionary. Rather than dealing with images deal with indices.

```
let diceArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")]


@IBAction func rollPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let index = Int.random(in: 0..<diceArray.count)
    diceFour.image = diceArray[index]
    print(index)
}
```

Be aware that indices of collection types are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more `Swift` to use an enum :

```swift
struct DiceFace: Int, CaseIterable {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
    ...
    case six = 6


    var image: UIImage {

        switch self {
            case .one:
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne")!
            ...
            case .sex:
            return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")!
        }
    }
}
```

Later you can create an Array with all your faces using DiceFace.allCases or manually :
`let allFaces: [DiceFace] = [.one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six]`

You can then access to a face's image using :

```swift
let randomFace = allFaces.shuffle().first!
let image = myFace.image
```